# react-native-webview handle blob downloads

Tags: android, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I'm trying to catch blob url downloads to handle them manually since android is not supporting them and crashes the app, but I can't find a way to do it.

onShouldStartLoadWithRequest seems like is being triggered only when the react app loads, but after that no longer triggers.

The code below just prints **http://10.0.2.2:9000/**, but never **blob**

There is any way to handle the blob downloads? I can't find anything for react-native-webview.

```
 const onShouldStartLoadWithRequest = (navigator: any) => {
    const {url} = navigator;
    console.log(url);
    if (url.includes('blob:')) {
      console.log('blob');
      webview.stopLoading();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  return (
    <WebView
      ref={(ref: any) => setWebView(ref)}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={{uri: 'http://10.0.2.2:9000/'}}
      style={{}}
      allowFileAccess={true}
      allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
      allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      mixedContentMode={'always'}
      onFileDownload={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
      onNavigationStateChange={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
    />
  );
```

**Environment:**

- OS: Android Embeded api 29
- react-native version: 0.63.3
- react-native-webview version: 11.0.2

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: Following some discussions on react-native-webview github, seems like might not be possible with the current implementation. Are some PRs open that should help with the issue